# Finding time and position of intersection of two moving, rotating bounding boxes

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, geometry, collision-detection

With an emphasis on finding the time (when the intersection starts), although the position is also important.  The bounding boxes (not axis aligned) have a position, rotation, velocity, and angular velocity (rate of rotation).  NO accelerations, which should really simplify things...  And I could probably remove the angular velocity component as well if necessary.  Either a continuous or iterative function would work, but unless the iterative function actively converges toward a solution (or lack thereof), it probably would be too slow.

I looked at [the SAT](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html), but it doesn't seem to be built to find the actual time of collision of moving objects.  It seems to only work with non-moving snapshots and is designed to work with more complicated objects than rectangles, so it actually seems ill-suited to this problem.

I've considered possibly drawing the trajectory out of each of the 8 points then somehow having a function for if a point is in or out of the other shape and getting a time range of that occurring, but I'm pretty lost on how to go about that.  One nice feature would be that it operates entirely with time and ignores the idea of discrete "steps", but it also strikes me as an inefficient approach.

No worries about broad phase (determining if it's worth seeing if these two bounding boxes may overlap), I already have that tackled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding an exact collision time is essentially a nonlinear root-finding problem.  This means that you will ultimately need an iterative approach to determine the final collision time -- but the clever bit in designing a collision solver is to avoid the root-solving when it isn't actually necessary...

The SAT is a theorem, not an algorithm:  it can be used to guide the design of a collision solver, but it is not one itself.  Briefly, it says that, if you can demonstrate a separating axis exists, the objects have not collided.  Conversely, if you can show that there is no such axis, then the objects currently *do* overlap.  As you point out, you can use this principle more-or-less directly, to design a binary "yes/no" query as to whether two objects in given positions overlap or not.

The difference with a collision solver is that the problem is animated, or kinetic: object position is a function of time.  One way to solve this problem is to start with a valid "yes/no" collision test, treat all the inequalities as functions of time, and use root-finding methods to look for the actual collision times on that basis.

There is a variety of existing methods in published academic literature.  I recommend some library research:  the best option probably depends on the details of your application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of thinking of two rectangles moving with speed `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` respectively, you may fix one of them (set its speed to `(0, 0)` ) and think of another one moving with speed `(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)`.

This way, the situation looks like one rectangle is immovable, and another one is passing by, possibly hitting the first.

- Assuming you don't have any angular velocity

[image]

Not hard to see, that you can then intersect 4 trajectories of a second rectangle (they are rays starting from different corners of a bounding box in `(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)` direction) with 4 sides of the first rectangle, standing still. Then you'll have to do the same vice versa - find the intersection of a first rectangle moving in reverse direction - `(-(x2 - x1), -(y2 - y1))` with 4 sides of a second rectangle. Choose the minimum distance between the all intersection points you've found (there might be 0-8 of them) and you're done.

Don't forget to consider many special cases - when the sides of both rectangles are parallel, when there's no intersection at all etc.

Note, this all is done in `O(1)` time, though the calculations are quite complex - 32 intersections of a ray and a segment.

- If you really wish your rectangles to rotate with some speed, I would suggest considering what @comingstorm has said: this is a problem of finding roots of a non-linear equation, however, even in such case, if you have a limited angular speed of your rectangles, you may split the task into a series of [ternary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search) subtasks, though I suppose this is just one of possible methods of solving non-linear problems.